# Typescript: Why is the result of the "typeof" operator correctly compared with literals and incorrectly with constants?

Tags: typescript

Typescript: Why is the result of the "typeof" operator correctly compared with literals and incorrectly with constants?

```typescript
function foo(param: string) { }

const s = 'string';

function test(param: string | number) {
    if (typeof (param) == 'string') foo(param);  // ok
    if (typeof (param) == s) foo(param);         // error
}
```

Error message: "Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript has special treatment for the use of typeof with the values `"string"`, `"number"`, `"boolean"`, and `"symbol"`, but only if they are literals.

The [TypeScript spec](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md) says this about these type guards:

> A type guard of the form typeof x === s, where **s is a string literal with the value 'string', 'number', or 'boolean'**,
>   when true, narrows the type of x to the given primitive type provided it is a subtype of the type of x, or, if the type of x is a union type, removes from the type of x all constituent types that aren't subtypes of the given primitive type, or
>   when false, removes the primitive type from the type of x.

As shown here, the right-side of the equals can take on one of three (actually four, including `'symbol'`) values in order to use `typeof` as a type guard. Anything else (e.g. `s`) and it doesn't work.

Side note: there's no need to use parentheses around `param` in `typeof (param)`.

Comment: To me, that quote implies that a variable of type `"string"` would interchangeable with the string literal `"string"`. Notice that `s` is type `"string"`, not `string`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I wouldn't necessarily read it that way, and empirically, I think OP has found that the RHS needs to be a literal. Regarding your second sentence, it appears the behavior is the same even if the `const` line is changed to `const s: string = 'string';`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Found the relevant part in the spec. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Nice find. I agree that language is a lot more definitive than in your previous quote.